# Cardinal arithmetic vs Ordinal Arithmetic

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that cardinal arithmetic is defined very different from ordinal arithmetic. But cardinal is one special kind of ordinal. So I want to ask if there is a connection between cardinal arithmetic and the arithmetic of cardinals defined in terms of ordinal.

Comment: What kind of connection are you looking for? The two arithmetics are essentially the same for finite cardinals and ordinals, while they are very different if you include infinite cardinals and ordinals: e.g, cardinal addition is commutative while ordinal addition is not.

Comment: Yes I know they coincide when in the finite case. But since the notation is exactly the same. I thought they could be the same under some conditions. Or it’s just a accident that the notations are the same?

Comment: I think it just a historical accident that additive notation is used for ordinal arithmetic even though it is not commutative.